How to pause inbetween commands in a loop in python?
Im trying to use tkinter to open a window with a button that if you click it it will wait 1 second,  open a new window, wait 1 second then open another new window
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

def two_window():
    for x in range(0, 2):
        sleep(1)
        new_window = Toplevel()
        

window = Tk()

window.geometry('500x500')

window.title("window test")

Button(window,text="two new windows",command=two_window).pack()

window.mainloop()

i tried this and when i press the button it waits around two seconds then opens two windows instead of waiting a second, opening a window, waiting a second, opening a window

You should not use sleep() in a tkinter program because tkinter can no longer run its mainloop(). You should look into using the after() method to get tkinter to schedule other functions to run at a later time.

Here's a quick example app that creates two Toplevel windows, one after the other, with a 1 second delay in between
import tkinter as tk


def two_window():
    tk.Toplevel(root)  # create first window immediately
    root.after(1000, tk.Toplevel, root)  # create second window after 1000 mS


root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Two new windows', command=two_window).pack()
root.mainloop()

the first window is created immediately when the button is clicked, followed by the second window which is created by the call to after in two_window

I'd try separating them like this
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

def two_window():
    sleep(1)
    new_window1 = Toplevel()
    new_window1.title("New Window 1")
    
    sleep(1)
    new_window2 = Toplevel()
    new_window2.title("New Window 2")

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.title("Window Test")

Button(window, text="Open Two New Windows", command=two_window).pack()

window.mainloop()


It's never a good idea to use sleep in a tkinter app, as the UI will hang for the duration of each call to sleep. The preferred method is to use tkinter's built-in after function

My bad, thank you for the correction. I'll leave this up as that is good information to have on this page
